# Seg Fault when passing strings through void pointers in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, hashtable, void-pointers, strcmp

I am relatively new to programming, and this is my first term working in C. So it is entirely possible that this could be a really simple mistake, or it is also possible that the explanation of what I did wrong could go over my head.

My program reads in a text file a builds a concordance in a hashmap which tells the user which words are in the text and how many times they occur. However, I continue to segfault (code 11), whenever I use the myCompare function. Here is its code:

```
int myCompare(void *s1, void *s2)
{
    printf("\n\nStarting myCompare...");
    printf("\n*s1: %s", (char *)s1);
    printf("\n*s2: %s", (char *)s2);

    char *key1 = (char *)s1;
    printf("\n\nkey1: %s", key1);
    char *key2 = (char *)s2;
    printf("\nkey2: %s", key2);

    return (strcmp(key1, key2));
}
```

I added some print statements to it and the function that calls it to give me a better idea of what is passing and exactly where it is segfaulting, but I am not sure why it is happening. Here is the output, if anyone needs more of the code to understand my mistake, just let me know. Thanks guys

```
struct hashLink {
    void* key;
    void* value;
    struct hashLink * next;
};

struct hashMap {
    hashLink ** table;
    int tableSize;
    int count;
};
```

...

```
void removeKey (struct hashMap * ht, void* k, comparator keyCompare, hashFuncPtr hashFunc)
{

struct hashLink *previousLink;
struct hashLink *currentLink;
int index = 0;

printf("\n\nVariables Declared");
printf("\nPre-hash index: %d", index);
index = ((*hashFunc)(k) % ht->tableSize);
void* keyPtr = &ht->table[index]->key;

printf("\nPost-hash index: %d", index);
printf("\nkeyPtr value: %p", keyPtr);
printf("\nk value: %p", k);

int testCompare = (*keyCompare)(k, keyPtr);
printf("\nkeyCompare: %d", testCompare);

if ((*keyCompare)(k, keyPtr) ==)){

... }
```

Terminal Output:

```
Starting hash2...
Passed key: and
value of r: 617

Post-hash index: 7
keyPtr value: 0x10e65dcd8
k value: 0x10e65df24

Starting myCompare...
*s1: and
*s2:

key1: and
key2:  
keyCompare: 65

Starting myCompare...
*s1:  
*s2: and

key1:  
Segmentation fault: 11
logout
```

Comment: Please explain how you are calling `myCompare`.

Comment: Add \n after all %s and rerun your program to see if that changes the printing. I don't think the problem is related to the function myCompare.

Comment: Are you sure neither of `s1` and `s2` is `NULL`?

Comment: What does valgrind says?

Comment: I guess `ht->table[index]->key` is a `char *`  . Use `void* keyPtr = ht->table[index]->key;` instead

Comment: @g.tsh there is a possibility that it could pass a NULL value, although I have done a check before passing values, and if NULL I set them to something... It still gave a segfault

Comment: Better to check for `NULL` at the point of use, not to rely on other code.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico - I tried that, but it segfaults at the `ht->table[index]->key` line

Comment: perhaps `ht->table[index]->key` is `NULL` or was not properly allocated

Comment: To get good help post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As things currently stand the problem is in code you haven't posted.

Comment: The problem is not a NULL pointer. Notice that the printing went fine inside myCompare when using s1 and s2 but failed using key1 and key2 even though they are just simple copies of s1 and s2. Further the problem is not in myCompare. Someone from the outside must be overwriting the memory used by myCompare. Could it be an ISR or another thread?

Comment: `ht->table[index]` can be null, so dereferencing `->key` is not allowed: `keyPtr = ht->table[index]->key`

Comment: @wildplasser - if you look at the output, you can see that the seg fault happens a long time after dereferencing key. So that can't be the problem.

Comment: Well: why don't you `printf("ThePoinTer: %p\n", `ht->table[index])` , before dereferencing it?

Comment: BTW you probably dont want the `&` in `void* keyPtr = &ht->table[index]->key;` , since it allready is a pointer. (but you did not show us the struct definition.

Comment: @GullySquad02 - The supplied code doesn't match the terminal output. The code only has one call of myCompare while the terminal output has two. In other words - we don't have the failing part of the code so we can't help. But for sure it isn't your the myCompare function causing problems.

Comment: The issue seems to be coming from how I am trying to de-reference `ht->table[index]->key`.

Answer (score 1):

If you code segfaults, then you probably are trying to operate with the pointers that contain garbage and do not actually point to any data that you own. Try using valgrind.

- Compile your code without optimization and with debugging symbols included

  ```
   g++ -O0 -g ./your_program.cpp -o ./your_program
  ```
- Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org)'s memory checker

  ```
   valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes ./your_program
  ```

It is likely that valgrind will tell you what exactly is wrong with your code.